# Python, make filename based on path and replace backslash

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Linux and in Python, I want to create a file name based on a path.  Imagine I have the path:

```
'/a/b/c'
```

I want to create a string from this where the slashes are replaced with an underscore character:

```
'a_b_c'
```

This is easy enough with replace:

```
'a/b/c/.replace('/', '_')
```

But I worry that this would not work on windows.  I don't know much about windows paths. Is there a straightforward way to make this operation windows-compatible?  Either through os.path functions, or through another replace call?

Thanks

Comment: Upvoted because many many people will have this question, and it was well stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
import os
out='a/b/c/'.replace(os.path.sep, '_')
print out
```

Comment: Thanks, os.path.sep is great.